# Is it bad practice to include the <head> in a partial page

Tags: html, web, freemarker

If I include the `<head>` of my page in a external file and then include it using a template engine like FreeMarker, would it be a bad practice?

I'm making a master page using Freemarker and I'm putting all the repetitive content in a external file. 
Then I include them using Freemarker directives like such:

`<#include "seccionesMasterPage/head.jsp"/>`

I made external files of:

- menu
- header
- footer

If I made a external file of the head and then include it, would it be a bad pratice?

Answer (score 1):

Well, including files make things much more convenient, you don't need to rewrite the sample code segments many times, and many frameworks also provide the extend function to let you make some different from the included file. I cannot think of any disadvantages.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12674235)

Comment: Okay, so what's the definition of answer for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From an HTML perspective, it's best to include  with every page you make. Since the  tag tends to be consistently the same across pages with links to the same CSS stylesheets, jQuery libraries, Javascript files, metadata etc. etc. it's definitely easier to have one external file to change than to have to dig through multiple HTML files all to change one thing.